# Polymorphish implementation with Hash Set for Specific data

Tags: java, polymorphism, linkedhashset

I had a set of objects(Parent). For a specific condition, I want to add extra data to that object. So I create a child class extended from the parent, put data to child and put it back to parent set. Theoretically, it is possible. But is it the good way to do like this? Please suggest me any other better way.

Another way is to create set of Child instead of Parent. Put data to child directly. But I can't do it as Parent sets will transform to Json and excess field is not required for all of the Parent object.

```
final LinkedHashSet<Parent> parentSet = new LinkedHashSet<Parent>();
parentSet.add(new Parent("AAA"));
parentSet.add(new Parent("ABC"));
parentSet.add(new Parent("DXX"));
parentSet.add(new Parent("GHI"));

final LinkedHashSet<Parent> childSet = new LinkedHashSet<Parent>();
final Iterator<Parent> iterator = parentSet.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  final Parent parent = iterator.next();
  if (parent.str.startsWith("A")) {
    iterator.remove();
    childSet.add(new Child(parent.str, 27));
  }
}
parentSet.addAll(childSet);
```

Answer (score 2):

The data you want to be shared among children should be placed in parent. Now you have only a child class if you come up with a BadChild class should this child have this methods? The best practice i have to suggest is to think like is a real world example.

For example do parent have to know the exact height of the child? Do child have to know the exact age of the parent?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a good way, unless you don't do any casting to reach `Child` instance. If you need to do anything special to `Child` class, please add a method to `Parent` class and then override it.